# ¿Qué realiza esta sentencia con el signo de exclamación?

Tags: base-de-datos, ms-access-2010

Estoy mirando una query que genera cierto resultado y me encuentro con una sentencia así:

```
SELECT tabla!columna AS alias FROM tabla
```

Mi duda es que realiza el signo `!`, lo probe en `Access 2007 -2010` y funciona, pero no entiendo la lógica.

Y será compatible con alguna versión de `SQL Server`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es un sintaxis no estándar de Access.

Es equivalente a:

```
SELECT tabla.columna AS alias FROM tabla
```

Comment: Pero cuál es la ciencia de hacer esto? Dar otro alias a la columna solamente ?

Comment: Oh! hace mucho no veía esto, de hecho no se si alguien continua usando MS Access. Es una equivalencia para dar un alias a una columna.